# convergent sequence in set of p-adic numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, p-adic-number-theory

How can we set up a sequence in $\mathbb{Q}$ which is convergent in $\mathbb{Q_5}$, but not convergent in $\mathbb{Q_7}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** What is $\lim_{n\to\infty}5^n$ in $\mathbb Q_5$?

Comment: not  sure what exactly is Q5...please more explain?

Comment: Let me see if I understand this. You are asking a question about the convergence of sequences in $\mathbb Q_5$, but you actually don't know what $\mathbb Q_5$ is. Am I right?

Comment: I know Q5 is a set of 5-adic numbers.  And each 5-adic number has a series form with respect to prime number 5

Comment: And do you know which distance you are working with in $\mathbb Q_5$?

Comment: Absolute value 5?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: for Q5 case I understand now, but 5^n in Q7 is not convergent because ord_7(5^n) does not exist?

Comment: No. Because, in $\mathbb Q_7$, the distance from $5^{n+1}$ to $5^n$ is constant (and different from $0$) for each natural $n$. Therefore, the sequence $(5^n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ doesn't converge there.

Comment: wait, First, for 5^n, it is a sequence like 5, 5^2, 5^3,.....each number is in Q_5, but how can we say each of them is in Q_7?  Then,  not quiet understand how to express the distance from 5$^{n+1}$ to 5$^n$ in Q$_7$.

Comment: The set $\mathbb Q$ is a subset of both $\mathbb Q_5$ and $\mathbb Q_7$. Therefore, each $5^n$ belongs to both of them.

Comment: so for the distance between 5$^n$ and 5$^{n+m}$, do you mean we need to take the partial sum and see whether it is a Cauchy? but even it is, we can only say the sequence of partial sum is convergent, right?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. This is a sequence, not a series. There are no partial sums here.